# DOM Node of the {{outlet}} corresponding to the (Ember) Route

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js, ember-router

Once a route has rendered, I would like to know the DOM node of the corresponding `outlet`.

Let's consider the project structure as below mentioned.

```
|____adapters
| |____application.js
|____app.js
|____index.html
|____models
| |____rental.js
|____resolver.js
|____router.js
|____routes
| |____rentals
| | |____rental.js
| |____rentals.js
|____styles
| |____app.css
|____templates
| |____application.hbs
| |____rentals
| | |____rental.hbs
| |____rentals.hbs
```

Let's consider the content of `application.hbs`, `rentals.hbs` and `rental.hbs` as below mentioned.

```
// application.hbs
<div class="container">  
  {{outlet}}
</div>

// rentals.hbs
<div>
 Yo!
 {{outlet}}
</div>

// rental.hbs
<div>
 So you are here!
</div>
```

So when `/rentals` is rendered, I would like know the DOM node corresponding to the `{{outlet}}` in the `application.hbs`.

Similarly when `/rentals/rental` is rendered, I would like know the DOM node corresponding to the `{{outlet}}` in the `rentals.hbs`.

May be some sort of `hook/callBack` that will get *executed when the route is rendered* and pass the `DOM node` as an `argument`.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Where specifically do you want to have access to this DOM node?

Comment: And what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: I need to focus the DOM node. It is for accessibility; add `tabindex=-1` and `focus()`